# Keyboard Column Selection for Sublime Text 2 on Windows

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext2

I've been trying to get column selection via keyboard bindings working on Windows.

The *Default (Windows).sublimekeymap* says this:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+up"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+down"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": true} },
```

And it is also documented here: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/column_selection.html However, every time I try to do column selection via the keyboard it doesn't work. Is this an environment specific problem or an actual bug? Or perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming you are getting multiple cursors when you go up in a block of text with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>, you then need to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to make the column selection.

If you are not getting multiple cursors at all, try changing the keybindings just to `up` and `down`, see if that works. It may be that your windows environment is using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>` for something else and prevents its use in Sublime.

Comment: Indeed. The Intel graphics adapter was capturing ctrl+alt+up and ctrl+alt+down. I had to: Right Click on the Desktop > Select Graphic Options > Hot Keys > Disable.

Comment: This was my issue, my graphics card was catching the default keyboard shortcut and so I simply assigned it to something else. If you've got an intel based graphics card, this issue will likely impact you.

Comment: I already had hotkeys disabled in the Intel graphics service, but it was still capturing ctrl+alt+up/down all the same. I had to change the actual hotkeys in the Intel graphics config to something else to get ctrl+alt+up/down to work in Sublime Text.

Comment: Just had the same problem, and indeed disabling the hotkeys wasn't enough. Why those are hotkeys in the first place (much less enabled by default) is utterly baffling.

Answer (score 10):

Not the right spot for this exactly, but if you RDP into a VM, the defaults won't work either.

I've redefined the line reordering binding of Ctrl+Shift for this purpose

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+up"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+down"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": true} }
```

Answer (score 9):

I think that is really late but, I found the following the most effective solution.

1. Put this in your "Key bindings defaults" and save it

   ```
   { "keys": ["alt+shift+up"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": false} },
   { "keys": ["alt+shift+down"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": true} },
   ```
2. After, you can use the following to make a column selection

   <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + [<kbd>Down</kbd> | <kbd>Up</kbd>]

Comment: These key commands do feel much more natural. They mimic the Notepad++ behavior. First you use `Alt+Shift+Up` to select the text then you just let go of `Alt` and keep holding `Shift` and select the columns of text you want using `Left` / `Right`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because of Winamp Global Hotkeys. Just remove that key combination from Winamp Preferences and it will work.