# Is there a way to do multiline editing a-la Visual Studio in Sublime?

Tags: visual-studio, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Visual Studio allows selecting a vertical piece of text, and then editing it. One has to hold Shift + Alt and move the cursor up-down left-right to make the selection.

[image]

I know there is Ctrl + D multi-cursor thing in Sublime, but it's not quite the same. 
So is there a way to do the multi-line editing a-la Visual Studio in Sublime?

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Standard way: Ctrl + Alt + Cursor (which flips the screen orientation on my laptop). The way that works: [Keyboard Column Selection for Sublime Text 2 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019468/keyboard-column-selection-for-sublime-text-2-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Move cursor where you want, hold <kbd>ctrl + shift</kbd> press ↓ a few times.

[image]

Press <kbd>tab</kbd>, then ← twice, type "Hello World,",

[image]

Press <kbd>esc</kbd> to leave multi-line mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You also can perform "square selection" using your mouse middle button.